# MySQL for loop in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I have 2 tables:

1. **employees** including columns id, name, job_title
2. **employees_audit** including columns id, employees_id, name, job_title, updated_date, action

I have a trigger which works fine for now... :

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_employees

AFTER UPDATE ON employees FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    IF OLD.name <> new.name THEN
        INSERT INTO employees_audit(employee_id, name,change_date,action)
        VALUES(OLD.id, concat('Old:', OLD.first_name, 'New:', new.first_name,'"'),NOW(),"update");
    END IF;

    IF OLD.job_title <> new.job_title THEN
        INSERT INTO employees_audit(employee_id, job_title, change_date,action)
        VALUES(OLD.id, concat('Old:', OLD.job_title, 'New:', new.job_title,'"'),NOW(),"update");
    END IF;

END$$
```

.. however if I update 2 conditions for the same id in my employees table my trigger creates 2 separate rows (one for each condition), but I would rather have my trigger just stating all updates for the same id on one row.

**For example:**

```
UPDATE employees
SET job_title = "programmer", first_name = "Vic"
WHERE employee_number =1;
```

Result from trigger [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAZPu.png)

Is it possible to rewrite my trigger into a loop somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `case` expression:

```
IF OLD.name <> NEW.name OR OLD.job_title <> NEW.job_title THEN
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (employee_id, name, job_title, change_date,action)
    VALUES(
        OLD.id, 
        CASE WHEN OLD.name <> NEW.name THEN 
            CONCAT('Old:', OLD.name, 'New:', NEW.name, '''')
        END,
        CASE WHEN OLD.job_title <> new.job_title THEN 
            CONCAT('Old:', OLD.job_title, 'New:', NEW.job_title, '''')
        END,
        NOW(), 
        'update'
END IF;
```

Note that I modified the column whose value is inserted in `name` (you were checking on `name` but inserting `fist_name`, which does not make a lot of sense). Also, I replaced the double quotes with single quotes (using double quotes for strings is not a good practice , although MySQL supports it, because it deviates from the SQL standard).

If the columns are nullable, additional logic is needed:

```
IF NOT OLD.name <=> NEW.name OR NOT OLD.job_title <=> NEW.job_title THEN
    INSERT INTO employees_audit (employee_id, name, job_title, change_date,action)
    VALUES(
        OLD.id, 
        CASE WHEN OLD.name <> NEW.name THEN 
            CONCAT('Old:', COALESCE(OLD.name, ''), 'New:', COALESCE(NEW.name, ''), '''')
        END,
        CASE WHEN OLD.job_title <> new.job_title THEN 
            CONCAT('Old:', COALESCE(OLD.job_title, ''), 'New:', COALESCE(NEW.job_title, ''), '''')
        END,
        NOW(), 
        'update'
END IF;
```